# Create a shiny app and when input URL, a csv file can be download

Tags: r

I want to create a shiny app and when I input URL, I can download a csv file. 
And I tried the following code. 
Warning: Error in paste: object 'sampleFile' not found

I think the problem is this part. The sampleFile can not be changed when different URl input.
sampleFile = str_extract(strsplit(input$url,"/")[[1]][6],".*(?=\?)")

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

liveBankAcct = read.csv("liveBankAcct.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
liveCustomerList = read.csv("liveCustomerList.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Milestone3Online-Ruiyu Xu"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$h3 ("Provide URL of Test Data"),
      textInput("url", "Enter URL of Test Data", ""),
      submitButton("submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      print("When result is ready to download, you will get an alert."),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dataReactive = reactive({
    sampleFile = str_extract(strsplit(input$url,"/")[[1]][6],".*(?=\\?)")
    download.file(input$url, sampleFile, mode = "wb")
    testfile = read.csv(sampleFile, header = TRUE) %>%
      left_join(liveCustomerList, by = "custID") %>%
      left_join(liveBankAcct, by = c("firstName" = "firstName", "lastName" = "lastName")) %>%
      mutate(rightAcctFlag = ifelse(bankAcctID == loginAcct, 1, 0)) %>%
      subset(select = c(custID, rightAcctFlag))
  })

  output$downloadData = downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){
      paste(sampleFile,"csv", sep = ".")
    },

    content = function(file){
      write_csv(dataReactive(), file)
    }
  )

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your `sampleFile` is inside of a `reactive` objects, that's why you get that Error.

Answer (score 0):

With a random url with a file name at the end, `sampleFile` is returned as NA.  In my case, the file is downloaded by `download.file` and saved as a file with the name "NA". I do not get the error you get.

There is a function in baseR that extracts the file name from a url: `basename`. You can off course do this with regex as well (I would guess that is what `basename` does but at the C level as it is an `.Internal` function).
Example:

```
url <- "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLS_10.xls"
> basename(url)
[1] "file_example_XLS_10.xls"
```

The function `strsplit(input$url,"/")[[1]][6]` looks a little awkward to me: `strsplit` returns in the case of a single url a list with one element which is a character vector. As you split by `/` the character vector elements will contain the text between the `/` characters. Only by chance will the interesting part, the file name, be located in the 6st element.